# simple string memory question in solidity

Tags: string, solidity

my question is simple. in first [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fnjek.png) of the image Remix asks me to insert memory, when I insert it it says it shouldn't be there. I am so confused. Am I not even understanding what the error is? Thanks

Comment: Please, can you share your smart contract code in this thread? (Not the image)

Comment: hi there! how do I do it? I tryed copy paste but it said my message is to long. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first error is because in local variables (inside functions), when it comes to structures, assignments or arrays, you have to explicitly declare the location of the data (memory, storage, call data), you can find more information about this in the documentation: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html?highlight=data%20location#data-location

Said this, check out this previous question and its answer: [How to interact with mapping of mappings for structs in solidity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71926036/how-to-interact-with-mapping-of-mappings-for-structs-in-solidity)

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply. I know I have to declare it, thats why I in fact did declared it, my entire questions is why it dont work when I do declare it. And in regards to that secound link you gave it doesnt help me at all (or at least I dont see how) since my problem is with strings.